# mongoDB - Regex search against partial field values

Tags: javascript, regex, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I've a collection of countries with country calling code in the country object. How can I find a country using calling code with a mobile number?

```
const countries = [
  {
    name: 'UAE',
    callingCode: 971
  },
  {
    name: 'USA',
    callingCode: 1
  },
  {
    name: 'UK',
    callingCode: 44
  }
];

const number = '971524500000'; // Input
```

How can I find country for the given mobile using regex in mongoose javascript;

Comment: why would you want to use regex for this?

Comment: because I think its faster than looping through all the countries and checking if the mobile number starts with one of the countryCode using String.startWith or String.indexOf

Comment: @RizwanYaqub : Not sure why there is request to **close** this question, What is your mongoDB version ? there is no direct functionality in Mongo that can support it but with few tricks we can try to do this in MongoDB v`4.2` up-to some extinct !!

Answer (score 0):

[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_country_calling_codes][1]

Take a look at the link above on country calling codes, and specifically see the section "Tree List".

One solution would be to implement a schema in Mongo based on this tree in order to decode the country codes.

So, a table could be created to store Mongo documents containing a field "1x" "2x" "21x" etc (the Y axis in the Tree List table).

Each of these documents could contain an array of sub-documents from x=0 to x=9 (the x axis in the Tree List table). The sub-document can contain the country name/code you are looking for. You can use a direct index into the array in the Mongo document for an efficient lookup.

I think you'll find this to be a pretty efficient implementation and should cover all the bases.

Answer (score 0):

If you can restructure your array to an object this would be the fastest

```js
const countries = 
  {
    971: 'UAE', 
    1: 'USA', 
    44: 'UK',
    
  }
;


var code = 44;

console.log(countries[code]);
```

```js
const countries = [
  {
    name: 'UAE',
    callingCode: 971
  },
  {
    name: 'USA',
    callingCode: 1
  },
  {
    name: 'UK',
    callingCode: 44
  }
];


 var myFound =countries.filter(myFunc.bind(this,44));
 
 

function myFunc(code,element) {


  if(element.callingCode == code){
     
     return element;
  }
}

console.log(myFound);
```

Answer (score 0):

On MongoDB v `4.2` - you can use [$let](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/let/index.html) & [$regexFind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/regexFind/index.html) to do this :

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $eq: [
          {
            $let: {
              vars: {
                value: {
                  $regexFind: {
                    input: "971524500000", // pass in as string
                    regex: { $toString: "$callingCode" }
                  }
                }
              },
              in: "$$value.idx",
            }
          },
          0
        ]
      }
    }
  }
]);
```

**Test :** [MongoDB-Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/xfc-mXj-DDf)

**Explanation :**

**General Use-case :**

In general regex searches - Will have an input which will be sub-string of actual string, **Ex.:-**

*Actual string in DB :* 'We can do it in mongo'

*Input :* mongo (`/mongo/` - will work)

**Your Use-case :**

From above case as `mongo` exists in actual string/value of db field then you can get that document, But your case is different :

*Actual string in DB :* mongo

*Input :* 'We can do it in mongo'

This doesn't work that way, So using normal `/We can do it in mongo/` isn't going help you here (Also doing few tricks with regex). So we need to make a trick to `$regexFind` operator. Unlike mongo documentation we need take `971524500000` into `input` field & regex as string value of `callingCode` field which is vice-versa to what's given in documentation.

So once we do that, We would get something like below :

```
{
    "match" : "971", /** value of callingCode field */
    "idx" : 0, /** Index of `971` in '971524500000' */
    "captures" : []
},{
        "match" : "1",
        "idx" : 2,
        "captures" : []
},
null /** 3rd doc no match */
```

As country code has to be at first of given number we need docs where `"idx" : 0` - So we're using `$let` to get index of returned object & checking against `0` & eventually getting respective docs using `$match`.

**Note :**

There is something you need to look into, Just in case if you've docs like below :

```
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5e8f67091aa1cc3d2158ade1"),
    "name": "USA",
    "callingCode": 1.0
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5e8f67091aa1cc3d2158ade3"),
    "name": "somecountry",
    "callingCode": 197.0
  }
```

& input is `1971524500000`, then this query will bring both docs in result. This will be the case you need to check on. Anyhow I would suggest to try this query, rather than getting all documents for collection to the code & extract required o/p this might be better to do.